# How to first create a file in a directory, and only then interact with it?

Tags: java

I have an application that serializes and deserializes an object in Java. But if you run the program through an infinite loop, then the application will save the files as if in memory, and at the end it will save it to disk

```
public static JMXMessage serializationAndDeserializationMessage(JMXMessage jmxMessage, String localDate, boolean temporary) {
        File file;
        if (temporary){
            file = new File("messagesShow/" + localDate + ".txt");
        } else {
           file = new File("messagesGet/" + localDate + ".txt");
        }

        FileOutputStream fileOutputStream;
        ObjectOutputStream objectOutputStream;
        FileInputStream fileInputStream;
        ObjectInputStream objectInputStream;
        JMXMessage JMXMessageReturnFileSerializable;

        try {
            fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
            objectOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(fileOutputStream);
            objectOutputStream.writeObject(jmxMessage);
            objectOutputStream.flush();
            objectOutputStream.close();

            fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
            objectInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(fileInputStream);
            JMXMessageReturnFileSerializable = (JMXMessage) objectInputStream.readObject();
            fileInputStream.close();
        } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

        return JMXMessageReturnFileSerializable;
    }
```

How can I make it so that during a cycle that I myself do not complete, files are created on disk and serialization occurs already in them? I am attaching the loop code.

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int a;
        while (true){
            a = scanner.nextInt();
            JMXMessage jmxMessage1 = Build.serializationAndDeserializationMessage(jmxMessage,localDate,true);
            System.out.println(jmxMessage1.toString());
            if (a == 1){
                break;
            }

        }
```

That is, while the cycle is going on, then the folder where the messages should fall is empty, but when the application ends, they already appear there. And I do not understand how to make it so that it was in RunTime

[image]

Comment: What you describe in the first few sentences is almost certainly not what's happening. Your code saves to disk and unless it throws some exception, it will do that. How do you verify that the directories are empty? The screenshot looks like it's from an IDE, is it possible that the IDE just re-scans the directories when your application finished? Did you check to see if the file exists in a terminal or file manager?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you are confusing the visibility of the files with that they are in memory. The files are most certainly being created on the filesystem. Depending on your operating system and filesystem it is possible that you can not view files being created until they are closed, or even when the application is closed, though the later is less common. It could even be the UI of the file browser that is caching the view. Try using a text directory listing (like `ls` in Linux/Mac, or `dir` in Windows).

Note that you are not closing `ObjectInputStream`. I don't think it will cause the file to be locked since you are closing `fileInputStream`. Not closing files may cause the files to be locked in some environments, until they are closed by the garbage collector or the program exits. To verify if there are pending open files while the application is running you could use the Linux/Mac `lsof` command. There is a similar tool called [Handle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/handle) for Windows.